# Syntax Error without details in Pervasive SQL

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

I am getting an error talking to a Pervasive SQL database, but without much details about what could be wrong. Do you have any advice about how I could debug where the problem is

```
Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.Lna.k: [LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Syntax Error.
   at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.Lna.w.a(String , ad , l )
   at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlCommand.a(Boolean , CommandBehavior , Boolean )
   at Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Here is the code

```cs
using (PsqlCommand command = new PsqlCommand(sql, psqlConnection))
{
  command.Parameters.Clear();
  command.CommandText = sql;
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KidDate", companyKIDDate);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KidTime", companyKIDTime);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KidMult", companyKIDMult);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KidComm", companyKIDComm);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateGmt", companyKIDDate);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeGmt", companyKIDTime);
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Seconds", companyKIDTime);  
  result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The query `sql` in the code is (keeping the weird formatting for exactitude).

```sql
INSERT INTO "FMUPDATE"
                        ("KID - date", "KID - time", "KID - user", "KID - mult", "KID - comm",
                        "Date GMT", "Time GMT",
                        "Flag",
                        "Pax Update",
                        "User ID",
                        "Count",
                        "Seconds",
                        "RockstarFlag")
                        VALUES(?, ?, 'RF01', ?, ?,
                        ?, ?,
                        1, 
                        1,
                        'RF01',
                        1,
                        ?,
                        1);
```

---

And here is the `PsqlTrace` of the error

```
00000001 09:21:53.704 T1 I43089283 Command::ExecuteNonQuery ENTER

    CommandText:      INSERT INTO "FMUPDATE"
                        ("KID - date", "KID - time", "KID - user", "KID - mult", "KID - comm",
                        "Date GMT", "Time GMT",
                        "Flag",
                        "Pax Update",
                        "User ID",
                        "Count",
                        "Seconds",
                        "RockstarFlag")
                        VALUES(?, ?, 'RF01', ?, ?,
                        ?, ?,
                        1, 
                        1,
                        'RF01',
                        1,
                        ?,
                        1);
    CommandType:      Text
    CommandTimeout:   30
    UpdatedRowSource: Both
    Par #1: @KidDate, Input, String, 0, System.Int32, 44755
    Par #2: @KidTime, Input, String, 0, System.Int32, 982
    Par #3: @KidMult, Input, String, 0, System.Int32, 128
    Par #4: @KidComm, Input, String, 0, System.Int32, 1
    Par #5: @DateGmt, Input, String, 0, System.Int32, 44755
    Par #6: @TimeGmt, Input, String, 0, System.Int32, 982
    Par #7: @Seconds, Input, String, 0, System.Int32, 982

    Error or Warning Received from Pervasive Server
    Number    = 0
    Message   = Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.Lna.k: [LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Syntax Error.
    Error Position = 37000

00000001 09:21:53.751 T1 I43089283 Command::ExecuteNonQuery EXIT
    Return: 0
```

Comment: First thing I would do to debug the error would be to take the statement being executed, copy it, and paste it into the PSQL / Actian Control Center and run it that way. You could also post the query here and let us take a look at it.  Might be able to give some ideas.

Comment: @mirtheil thanks for your reply. I edited my question. Also I forgot to mentioned that most of the time it works, but under certain condition it does not. Also the query seems to be executed as I can query the DB afterward and the data is here.

Comment: Also, I am more fishing for ways for get more debug information on a PSQL engine, rather than help to debug my very specific problem. Do you have any experience in PSQL and could help me to activate any sort of logs?

Comment: I got a MDK.TRA file of the error, but I am not sure how to read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MKDE.TRA file is a Btrieve / Transactional engine level trace.  The error you are seeing is a Relational engine error.  Some Relational engine errors are the same as Transactional / Btrieve errors but most are not.  You can turn on tracing within the Pervasive.Data.SqlClient interface using code like below:

```
PsqlTrace.TraceFile = "C:\\source\\debug\\MyTrace.txt";
PsqlTrace.RecreateTrace = 1;
PsqlTrace.EnableTrace = 1;
```

This will generate a file that has a format like:

```
Assembly Name:         Pervasive.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c84cd5c63851e072
Assembly File Version: 4.1.0.005024

00000001 19:48:31.703 T1 I30015890 Command::ExecuteNonQuery ENTER

    CommandText:      INSERT INTO Table1 ("KID -NAME", name, number) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    CommandType:      Text
    CommandTimeout:   30
    UpdatedRowSource: Both
    Par #1: @KIDname, Input, String, 0, System.String, "name"
    Par #2: name, Input, String, 0, System.String, "name"
    Par #3: number, Input, String, 0, System.Int32, 88

    Error or Warning Received from Pervasive Server
    Number    = 0
    Message   = Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.Lna.w: [LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface]Invalid column name: 'KID -NAME'.
    Error Position = 0

00000001 19:48:31.759 T1 I30015890 Command::ExecuteNonQuery EXIT
    Return: 0
```

Since this doesn't always happen, I would enable / disable the trace only around the calls that fail.  Once you get the error, take a look at the trace and see if there's any more information.  Posting here might get more eyes on it.  If I had to guess, I would say that some value you are passing is invalid (00-00-0000 for a date, string for an integer, etc.).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I think it was the `;` at the end of my SQL :/ well two days well spent, I know a lot about psql now at least haha

Comment: I added the PsqlTrace of the error in my question as well, but yeah it does not really give me a nice message about where the error actually was... I had to compare with other queries in the code to notice they never ended with a `;`. Also the weird thing is that it only happen in one of the server and not the other. Maybe there are some hidden configuration about the driver that I ignore.